# Rails/Devise: Nil location provided. Can't build URI. on Password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4.2 and Devise. Whenever I try to use the reset password page I get the following error:

```
Nil location provided. Can't build URI. on Password reset
```

In production it comes with a 500 internal server error.

The email with the reset token does actually send. And if user opens the link in their email they can return to the site to change the password. Despite this, the 500 error will always arise when the 'reset password button' is clicked.

I've used devise many times before, and have never had this issue. I suspected it might have something to do following this tutorial:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

and explicitly writing the `resource_name`, `resource` and `devise_mapping` methods in my application controller, yet they haven't interfered with any other devise route, and even after commenting them out, the error has persisted.

Edit:

I don't have a `PasswordController` just sticking to most of the default settings of Devise. Nor am I using `respond_with` anywhere in my app.

My Devise Model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :lockable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:stripe_connect]


    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :time_zone, presence: true
    has_one :teacher, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :bookings, foreign_key: :student_id
    has_many :reviews, foreign_key: :student_id, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates_format_of :email, with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX

end
```

Edit 3:

Here are the relevant routes:

```
get 'sessions/create'
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
resources :users, :only =>[:show]

devise_scope :user do
    get 'bookings', to: 'bookings#bookings'
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post, :class => "sky-form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <h3 class="text-center"><%= t('.header') %></h3>
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="label col col-4"><%= t('.email') %></label>
        <div class="col col-8">
          <label class="input">
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="text-right">
      <%= f.submit t('.resetpwbtn'), class: "btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg" %>
    </footer>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You are calling JSON api?

Comment: Shiv Raj: No, I'm not.

Comment: You need to share your Devise model, PasswordsController if there any, and other information like migration file generated by Devise, so that we know more about this.

Comment: I just wrote in the method. But am not using a `PasswordsController`

Answer (score 26):

This can happen with devise when using the new turbo/hotwire.

In my case I customized the forms to set `"data-turbo": "false"`

Like so:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { "data-turbo": "false", method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

If you haven't done so, you will need to use Devise custom views: https://dev.to/n350071/customize-view-of-devise-3k95

Comment: Obviously not the original issue, but this saved me a bazillion hours of debugging on Rails 7 / Hotwire / Turbo. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This resolved my issue, too (Rails 6.1 with Webpacker & @hotwired/turbo-rails packaged in application.js; Devise 4.8.1 bundled)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `respond_with` it can only be used with resource. I've had that problem and the fix was to you `render`.

If this is the case something like

```
render :text => 'false'
```

could possibly help. But to be sure we would have to see your model to figure out more of the issue.

The other issue, could be that `responds_with` expects an `ActiveRecord` object for it to map out the routes.

I am not exactly sure how it is implemented within your code, but these are some ways that I have solved this error in the past.

Comment: I just looked, and am not using `respond_with` anywhere on my app. I updated with my model, if you'd care to look.

Comment: What does your routes look like, along with the implementation in the view? Does this work in development?

Comment: I added the relevant routes and the view. Also no, it doesn't work in development either. Actually the email does send and the process works. It is simply that after the form submits the site crashes.

Comment: The problem is `respond_with` in the devise controller: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L19

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in another project. In my case, I was missing a template file for the `create` action. If we look at devise's create function, it uses the `respond_with` method to render correct information depending on the mime type of the "Accept" header of the request. With an html response, for example, it's might be trying to load `create.html.erb` (or another template type depending on your config).

A bit late, hope it helps